# Prove $ f : [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1] $ continuous function is bounded by x+r

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

let $A \subset [0,1]\hspace0.3cm$ and $\hspace0.1cm$ $A\cap(0,1] \neq \emptyset \hspace0.3cm $

let $ f : [0,1] \to [0,1] $ be a continuous  function so that

$\forall x \in [0,1] \hspace0.5cm $    $x-\sup A \lt  f(x) \lt x+\sup A \hspace0.5cm (1)$

**prove**: $\hspace0.1cm$
$\exists r\in A$ such that $\forall x\in[0,1]$

$x-r \lt f(x) \lt x+r$

suppose we have  $A = \{0,y \}$

let $y = 0$
$\implies$ $x \lt f(x) \lt x$  $\hspace0.3cm$ contradiction

$y\neq 0$

we get $x-y \lt f(x) \lt x+y$ for some $y \in [0,1]$

so this obviously holds for $2$ elements, but I don't know how to do the proof

$f$ has a fixed point $c \implies c-\sup A \lt c \lt c+ \sup A$

$f$ is continuous on a compact set so it attains its maximum and minimum value,

I know those two things are true but I dont know how to use them

Comment: "Let $y=0.$" Then $A\cap (0,1]=\emptyset.$

Comment: I think you mean $x-y<f(x),$ not $x+y<f(xj.$

Comment: thank you, fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite the condition $$x-\sup A<f(x)<x+\sup A$$ as $$|f(x)-x|<\sup A.\tag1$$

But $g(x)=|f(x)-x|$ is continuous on a compact set $[0,1],$ so $\sup_{x\in[0,1]} g(x) =g(x_0)$ for some $x_0\in [0,1].$ We have $g(x_0)<\sup A,$ by $(1),$ so there must be an $a\in A$ such that $g(x_0)<a.$

But then, for any $x\in[0,1],$ $g(x)\leq g(x_0)<a.$ So: $$|x-f(x)|<a$$ which is equivalent to $$x-a<f(x)<x+a.$$